# Matplotlib complains about shape of networkx adjacency matrix

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

The following code results in an error unpacking the shape of my matrix in `figaspect`, but the shape seems to be correct (a 4 by 4 2D array).  Am I doing something dumb?

```py
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
g = nx.Graph()
g.add_edge(1, 2)
g.add_edge(2, 3)
g.add_edge(3, 4)
matrix = nx.to_scipy_sparse_matrix(g)
print(matrix.shape)
plt.matshow(matrix)
plt.show()
```

errors with:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-118-70cfbe8cdb62> in <module>
      7 matrix = nx.to_scipy_sparse_matrix(g)
      8 print(matrix.shape)
----> 9 plt.matshow(matrix)
     10 plt.show()

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py in matshow(A, fignum, **kwargs)
   2180         # Extract actual aspect ratio of array and make appropriately sized
   2181         # figure.
-> 2182         fig = figure(fignum, figsize=figaspect(A))
   2183         ax = fig.add_axes([0.15, 0.09, 0.775, 0.775])
   2184     im = ax.matshow(A, **kwargs)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py in figaspect(arg)
   2740     # Extract the aspect ratio of the array
   2741     if isarray:
-> 2742         nr, nc = arg.shape[:2]
   2743         arr_ratio = nr / nc
   2744     else:

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)
```

but the printed shape is (4, 4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `todense`:

```
plt.matshow(matrix.todense())
```

Where,

```
print(matrix)
```

Outputs:

```
  (0, 1)    1
  (1, 0)    1
  (1, 2)    1
  (2, 1)    1
  (2, 3)    1
  (3, 2)    1
```

And,

```
print(matrix.todense())
```

Outputs:

```
[[0 1 0 0]
 [1 0 1 0]
 [0 1 0 1]
 [0 0 1 0]]
```

Plottting:

[image]

Comment: Or use `nx.to_numpy_matrix(g)`